# Android Mpchart configure y axis value (not the y axis string value)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

As of now mpchart decides which y values should be shown (depends upon the given data points. But i wanted to configure y values as per my need.
for example. 
1. Max  y value count to be 4 (including 0)
2. if data points are between 0 to 5, then y axis value increment of 1
3. if max value is 7, then increment of 2 (like 0,2,4,6)
4. if max 28, then increment of 8 (like 0,8,16,24)

i know some value will be shown above the graph as some value are greater than max y value.

Can you let me know, if this is possible through mpchart ?

Comment: Not very clear, but have you looked at the examples for `ValueFormatter` and `AxisValueFormatter`?

Comment: Question is ambiguous but as I understand some of it can be done by using MpAndroid Charts.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface). The ValueFormatter interface can be used to format x axis and Y axis values.

Comment: Thanks for input, but i think ValueFormatter or AxisValueFormatter are used to change the X or Y axis string value (like if y axis value comes as 5, 6,8, 23 then change to similar value string $5,$6,$8,$23).

Comment: But my requirement is if y axis dataset is (for example) 1, 3,4,7,9,30 then i want to decide which Y axis values should be displayed in y axis instead Mpchart decide.   Because Mpchart may show y axis as 0, 10,20,30.   But i wanted in different format like 0,8,16,24. so this not only the value string change, it is actual y axis value change,  Is it possible to achieve using mpchart ?

Comment: no i think you can change value also. If you think that 5,6,8,23 will change to $5,$6...etc that's not correct, You have full control of values to be shown u can show anything based on the value you set to Y axis.

Comment: But if we change value in ValueFormatter, whether graph will be scaled as per new value. Suppose y axis value 5 is changed to 10 and bar graph (one of the value) 7. Originally bar graph will be shown above the y axis value 5, if value is change to 10 then bar graph should come below the 10 y axis value. I dont think if we change the value in valueFormatter graph will changes. Let me know if my understanding is correct

Comment: That must change. Otherwise there is no point of having value formatter. Just give a try.

Comment: I tried using ValueFormatter, able to change the data. But graph doenst change according to changed data. Can you give an example ?   As per me Value formatter is used only to change the styling of data, but the data itself